# Terminal icon and command

Tags: command-line, icons

This is a double question.

The first one is: can I put a terminal shortcut on an Ubuntu desktop and how (the double-click is supposed to launch the terminal window)

The second is: is it possible to launch the terminal directly with a command? That is, any time it starts it must directly call *sudo apt-get...*

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu ! Typically it is advised to split posts into one question per post. In your case , it can be condensed into one, because to make shortcut you actually need to know the command.

Comment: It is best if you address one issue per question :)

Comment: @Serg: Oh, thanks for your comment! Ron: is the answer too complex?

Comment: @kos: maybe half duplicate at this point   ;-)

Comment: Answer isn't complex, but has bunch of tiny bits that need explaining

Comment: Wrong question, sorry: http://askubuntu.com/q/64222/380067. Maybe the second answer is more suitable if you don't want to install additional packages.

Comment: I love Ubuntu but this should be more simple...  :-(

Comment: I'm writing an answer, will post soon

Comment: Answer posted, slightly edited , let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: Upon re-reading it's not clear what you're trying to do, do you want to know how to launch the terminal by double-clicking on a shortcut and run `sudo apt-get [...]` automatically *in that specific terminal* or do you want to know how to launch the terminal by double-clicking on a shortcut and run `sudo apt-get [...]` automatically *in whatever terminal*? If the first one please clarify, If the second one please split the post into two different questions.

Comment: @kos: the ideal it would be the possibility to have on the same computer two different terminal icons, one opening a regular terminal window and another one (custom) launching the terminal from desktop directly with a certain command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual command that launches Terminal is . . .`gnome-terminal`. There are actually many different Terminal Emulators. For instance, I am using `sakura` right now, a lot of people like `Terminator` , the classic one is `xterm` (which by the way also comes with Ubuntu and pretty much any Linux distro that has graphical environment).

What you call "shortcut" in Windows world is an `.lnk` file. In Ubuntu world there is something similar, `.desktop` files. They are used for a lot more than just running some app - you can also use them to launch stuff on GUI login if you put those files into `.config/autostart` folder (notice the leading dot). The structure of those files is as follows :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=**actual command goes here**
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

So knowing that you could create  a file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MY-CUSTOM-APP
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/apps/terminal.png
```

The Icon field can be ignored sometimes, but if you want the shortcut to look pretty, give it a full path to the image.

Also, there exists a folder with all the `.desktop` files, the `/usr/share/applications`, and there is `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`. One could copy over such file to `/home/user/Desktop/`. Problem is, those files are owned by `root` user, so you have to do something along these lines:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop /home/$USER/Desktop/Terminal.desktop

chown $USER:USER /home/$USER/Desktop/Terminal.desktop

chmod +x /home/$USER/Desktop/Terminal.desktop
```

Comment: a little question: I must tell a 10 years old boy he can change the icon. He doesn't know anything about permissions but he can put the icon in the Pictures folder. I can tell him not to delete it, but isn't there any way to protect that icon from accidental removal?

Comment: (it should be something he can do without using the terminal, of course)

Comment: @IanBell In file manager, you can right click on an image, select properties option, and it should display small properties window. There will be the Permissions tab, where you can set the permissions form drop down menus.  That should prevent deletion by others, but not the owner.  I'll think if there's any other way, but probably this is the best I can offer